# Reduced form for using an OR operator?

Tags: ios, swift

Is there a way to make this statement shorter?

```
let number = 1
if number == 0 || number == 1 {
    print("ok")
}
```

like

```
let number = 1
if number == (0 || 1) {
    print("ok")
}
```

This one doesn't work but I was wondering if there is a shorter way that I am not aware of.

EDIT:

I am aware of the switch case that might be useful when many case appear, but in my case I was more looking for something to use with ternary operators:

```
let oldNumber = 1
let newNumber = (oldNumber = 0 || 1) ? 4 : 13
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Boolean equation expressions are evaluated always providing left (`number`) and right (`0`) side.
Not really shorter but you could write

```
let number = 1
if (0...1).contains(number) {
  print("ok")
}
```

Comment: @Nico it that case you could create an `Array` or a `Set` from those elements instead of the `(0...1)`

Comment: yeah that's why I deleted my comment when I realised it ;)

Answer (score 1):

Little poor but nevertheless.

```
let number = 1
print((0...1).contains(number) ? "ok" : "bad")
```

Or:

```
let a = 1
let b = (0...1).contains(a) ? 4 : 5
```

Answer (score 1):

just for variety:

```
    let c = { (number:Int, args:Int...) -> Bool in return args.contains(number) }

    let number = 1;
    if c(number, 0,1,9,4) {
        print("ok")
    }
```

only shorter if you are going to reuse the closure, has the advantage over the 0...1 range because you can specify a disjoint set of numbers. Can be used for inline if statements etc quite neatly

Answer (score 0):

When checking for several possible cases the `switch` statement might be more concise.

```
let number = 1
switch (number) {
case 0, 1:
    print("ok")
default:
    print("something else")
}
```

Comment: I edited my question. I'm aware of the switch statement, but was more looking for a way to be used in a ternary operators